# How to ensure lower server load in Django

Tags: python, django, server

I'm working on a `Django` web app. The app includes messages that will self-delete after a certain amount of time. I'm using `timezone.now()` as the sent time and the user inputs a `timedelta` to display the message until. I'm checking to see if the message should delete itself by checking if current time is after sent time plus the time delta. Will this place a heavy load on the server? How frequently will it automatically check? Is there a way that I can tell it to check once a minute (or otherwise set the frequency)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How frequently will it automatically check?

who is "it" ? If you mean "the django process", then it will NOT check anything by itself. You will have to use either a cronjob or some async queue to take care of removing "dead" messages.

> Is there a way that I can tell it to check once a minute (or otherwise set the frequency)?

Well yes, cf above. cronjobs are the simplest solution, async queues (like celery) are much more heavy-weight but if you have a lot of "off-band" processing (processes you want to launch from the request/response cycle BUT execute outside of it) then it's the way to go.

> Will this place a heavy load on the server?

It's totally impossible to answer this. It depends on your exact models, the way you write the "check & clean" code, and, of course, data volumes. But using either a cronjob or an async queue this won't run within the django server process(es) itself, and can even be runned on another server as long as it can access the database. IOW the load will be on the database mostly (well, on the server running the process too of course but given your problem description a simple SQL delete query should be enough so..).